# Не работают кнопки увеличения/уменьшения яркости. Debian 8, Lenovo Z500

Tags: debian, gnome

Переехал на 8ой дебиан. Всё завелось замечательно и без каких-либо проблем, кроме яркости дисплея ноутбука - она была установлена в минимум и ни через настройки, ни через файлы в **/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight**, ни через функциональные клавиши она не менялась

Модель ноутбука lenovo z500 (intel graphics 4000), на всякий случай, вот что даёт lspci:

```
# lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Согласно рекомендациям в сети добавил опцию в конфиг GRUB'a:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Однако это не помогло, а помогло:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=splash"
```

И отключение в БИОСе ноутбука **Bios Back Flash**

Теперь яркость на максимуме, но она всё равно не регулируется ни через настройки, ни через Fn+F11/F12

Что я попробовал еще:

Драйвера обновлял, сейчас стоит такое:

```
Пакет: xserver-xorg-video-intel                  
Состояние: установлен
Автоматически установлен: да
Версия: 2:2.21.15-2+b2
```

В каталоге **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/** создал файлик **80-backlight.conf** со следующим содержимым:

```
Section "Device" 
Identifier "Intel Graphics" 
Driver "intel" 
Option "AccelMethod" "sna" 
Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight" # use your backlight that works here 
BusID "PCI:0:2:0" 
EndSection
```

Однако это не помогло.

Примечательно, что в меню граба до старта загрузки системы яркость регулируется через функциональные клавиши, т.е. где-то в системе что-то не так.

Где выпрямлять руки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вспомнил, что задавал этот вопрос. И раз уж у меня есть решение, то предоставлю его, вдруг кому поможет.

Во-первых рекомендую выполнить шаги, описанные [здесь](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/display#TOC-Brightness-of-the-display-is-wrong-and-not-adjustable) (начиная с 6го пункта и далее). В большинстве случаев описанные там решения помогают.

Однако мне они не помогли, а помогло вот что:

1. Идём в `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` (если файла нет, то создаём) и пишем туда:

`Section "Device"
     Identifier "card0"
     Driver "intel"
     Option "Backlight" "ideapad"
     BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection`

2. Добавляем опции для ядра. Для этого открываем `/etc/default/grub`, и превращаем строку `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` в:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=video video.use_native_backlight=0"`

3. Делаем конфиг для grub'a:

`sudo update-grub`

либо же

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

4. Ребут и проверяем. У меня всё заработало.

Повторюсь, что эти 4 пункта, судя по сообщениям на форумах, скорее исключение, которое помогло мне, но в большинстве случаев помогают действия описанные на ресурсе по ссылке выше.

Кстати, для Ubuntu тоже, скорее всего, подойдёт, если есть проблемы с яркостью и кнопками Fn.

Comment: помогает ответ выше, однако тогда nvidia видеокарта "перестает существовать в системе" в lspci её вообще тогда нету

Comment: @stawrik с nvidia интересно было бы поиграть, но у меня только intel. Я пока изучал вопрос, видел советы поставить бамблби, если карточки от нвидии. Хотя лично мне кажется это далеко далеко не идеальным решением. Бамблби может и подтягивает что-то необходимое, но это скорее решение последствий, а не изначальной проблемы. Т.е. не факт, что при каком-нибудь обновлении все снова не сдохнет =)

Answer (score 0):

На ноутбуке Samsung NP300E под Debian 9 помогло только изменение строки в:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

Никакие изменения xorg и прочие делать не пришлось. Теперь всё работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста укажите, какие изменения  в /etc/default/grub.

Comment: изменил настройку на GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=video video.use_native_backlight=0", как и рекомендовал  Mr. Brightside