# debian 9 яркость ноутбук lenovo z500

Tags: debian

перепробовал всё что есть в этой теме.

[Не работают кнопки увеличения/уменьшения яркости. Debian 8, Lenozo Z500](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469821/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-debian-8-lenozo-z500)

если выставляю в grub 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_backlight=vendor"
то кнопки fn + яркость прибавить убавить работают, но максимальная яркость экрана ниже, чем должна быть.

если добавить туда же acpi_osi=Linux тогда с яркостью все хорошо и регулируется, но тогда пропадает видеокарта nvidia из системы вовсе(не выводится в lspci).

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)

пробовал это все на kali linux rolling на gnome3 с проприетарными драйверами nvidia
сейчаc debian 9 на kde, все аналогично, так что не думаю что это важно.

acpi_backlight=vendor так же нужен для работы bbswitch

идеально было бы, если есть файл в котором можно увеличить максимальное значение яркости или может быть команда.

насколько я понял надо создать конфиг для xorg, и использовать его в grub, но так как новичок в linux не знаю, что да как, и почему. Ещё интересно "vendor" откуда это, что это и где можно посмотреть настройки этого. А так же acpi_osi=Linux. :)

Простите если что не по правилам оформил. Заранее спасибо.

когда в grub выставляю acpi_osi=Linux то используется intel_backlight(в sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight) яроксть по максимуму, не регулируется и пропадает nvidia

если acpi_backlight=vendor то используется ideapad(sys/class/backlight/ideapad) регулируется, есть nvidia, но при исопльзовании тогда яркость ниже чем должна быть(максимум темнее чем должно быть)

я даже готов пожертвовать регулировкой лишь бы была по максимуму и nvidia не отпадала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил.

Поставил в grub вместо `acpi_backlight=vendor` - `acpi_backlight=video`, а `acpi_osi=Linux` удалил (из-за него пропадала nVidia). Регулировка работает, яркость что надо, bbswitch тоже в норме. Все работает без каких либо дополнительных конфигов в xorg.